# Twitter Bootstrap and Flat UI Best Practice

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to bootstrap and flat UI design. I want to overwrite the CSS by bootstrap and flat ui. Should I create a new class(or just the same class) for it and a custom style.css to overwrite it or should I directly edit bootstrap.css? Which is the best practice when dealing with CSS Frameworks?

Comment: I would overwrite them in the bootsrap.css file, that way you wouldn't need to load multiple css files just to overwrite one of them. also, check out http://www.flathemes.com/index.html. it's based on flat ui and bootstrap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most straightforward approach to override Bootstrap’s styles is to follow the bootstrap.css with your own "styles.css"...

For example, to make all of the buttons more rounded you;d add the following code to your styles.css...

```
.btn {
   -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
   -moz-border-radius: 20px;
   border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Or, (a better approach) is to extend the Bootstrap styles with your own custom classes. This way you don't impact/override all of the elements for a particular class.

```
.btn-special {
   background-color:#cc3333;
   color:#fff;
}
```

Here's a demo: http://bootply.com/106060

Answer (score 3):

Editing bootstrap's CSS could potentially break bootstrap. If you understand specificity and the cascading nature of stylesheets, you could create your own styles in a separate stylesheet to override bootstrap's CSS.